# How to let the objects be changed just by his creator

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I've got a project where the user can create a model Parceiros and in that model is a model linking all the Servicos to that model Parceiros. The problem is that the Parceiros should be linked to the current user as the only way to create a Parceiros object is logging in before. After that the only user that should be able to change the Parceiros fields or Servicos should be the current user that created o Parceiros object.
I've read some questions and tried with context processors, but didn't manage to get the Parceiros linked to the user.

services/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from phone_field import PhoneField
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify


User = get_user_model()

class Parceiros (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    endereco = models.TextField(max_length=400, blank=True)
    responsavel = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tel = PhoneField(max_length=12)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    ativo = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Servicos (models.Model):
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    objetivo = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    parceiro = models.ForeignKey(Parceiros, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    preco = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    telefone = PhoneField(max_length=12, default='21968151502')

def get_image_filename(instance, filename):
    tipo = instance.services.tipo
    slug = slugify(tipo)
    return "servicos_imagens/%s-%s" % (slug, filename)

class Imagens (models.Model):
    servicos = models.ForeignKey(Servicos, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    imagem = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_filename)
```

services/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Servicos, Parceiros, Imagens
from django.views.generic import UpdateView, DetailView, ListView
from .forms import ParceirosForm, ServicosForm, ImagensForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.context_processors import auth


def home_view(request):
    serv = Servicos.objects.all()
    context = {'serv': serv }
    return render (request, 'home.html', context)


@login_required
def parceiros_create(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = ParceirosForm(request.POST)
        Parceiros.user = auth.user
        if form.is_valid():
            parceiro = form.save(commit=False)
            parceiro.save()
        return redirect('home2')
    else:
        form = ParceirosForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render (request, 'parceiroform.html', context)


def parceirosview(request):
    user = Servicos.parceiro
    serv = Servicos.objects.get(parceiro=user)
    context = {'serv': serv}
    return render(request, 'parceiro.html', context)


class ServicoView(DetailView):
    model = Servicos



class ServicoUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Servicos
    template_name = 'servicoform.html'
```

services/forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Servicos, Imagens, Parceiros
from phone_field import PhoneField

class ParceirosForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        prefix = 'parceiro'
        model = Parceiros
        fields = ['nome', 'endereco', 'responsavel', 'tel']



class ServicosForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tipo = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    objetivo = forms.CharField(max_length=500)
    preco = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    telefone = PhoneField(max_length=12)

    class Meta:
        prefix = 'service'
        model = Servicos
        fields = ['tipo', 'objetivo', 'preco', 'telefone']


class ImagensForm(forms.ModelForm):
    imagem = forms.ImageField(label='image')

    class Meta:
        model = Imagens
        fields = ['imagem']
```

Comment: Your models.py is the wrong one (please copy the correct code). Also you can remove all the code for login/registration as it has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Parceiros` is the class, so `Parceiros.user = auth.user` doesn't do anything.

When saving your form, you should assign the `user` to the actual **instance** of the model you're saving:

```
if form.is_valid():
    parceiro = form.save(commit=False)
    parceiro.user = request.user  # assuming user is a FK field on Parceiros
    parceiro.save()
```

Note that you should use `request.user` (not `auth.user`) which is the currently logged in user.

For the `UpdateView`s, you only need to change the `queryset` in order to ensure that only instances belonging to that user can be changed:

```python
# inside class ServicoUpdate
# Servico is related to User via the Parceiros model

def get_queryset(self):
     return super().get_queryset().filter(parceiro__user=self.request.user)

# inside class ParceiroUpdate

def get_queryset(self):
     return super().get_queryset().filter(user=self.request.user)
```

And similarly for any other view that requires to restrict access to only the current logged in user's instances, if using a class-based view, override `get_queryset()`.

Comment: table services_parceiros has no column named user_id.
why should i get the user for the id?

Comment: when i try to create a Parceiros object i get this error: 
table services_parceiros has no column named user_id.
is that why i'm not using a ModelUser?

Comment: sorry for taking so long to answer back, just got into a new job and this one is a private project mine. i'm not getting why there is no column for user_id is that because i created my User_auth on forms.py besides models.py

HELPS ME DIRK PLEASE